# Configure STM32 to sleep inside an ISR

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, interrupts, sleep

I am doing a test project to test the STM32's sleep mode feature. The project involves two microcontrollers:

- STM32F411 with a push button, which when pressed, sends data through SPI to an STM32F303 microcontroller. This microcontroller is also equipped with an LED indicating that it has send data through SPI.
- STM32F303 which receives the data through an SPI interrupt and a blue LED that blinks once it receives the correct sequence of data

I have implemented the SPI Interrupt Send/Receive successfully, and also sleep modes on both microcontrollers successfully with the following code:

```
int main(){
   ...
   ...
   /* Suspend Tick increment to prevent wakeup by Systick interrupt */
   HAL_SuspendTick();
   /* Sleep immediately after every successful interrupt execution */
   HAL_PWR_EnableSleepOnExit();
   /* Request to enter SLEEP mode through WFI */
   HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);
   /* Resume Tick interrupt if disabled prior to sleep entry */
   HAL_ResumeTick();

   while(1){
      ...
      ...
   }
}
```

With the above code, I have verified that whatever happens in the while loop does not execute because both microcontrollers will only wake up when an interrupt occurs and goes back to sleep through the `HAL_PWR_EnableSleepOnExit()` (without this, the while loop will execute and sleep mode only occurs once). Furthermore, on the STM32F411, I also verified that it was in sleep mode by checking the current consumption through the IDD ports.

I am attempting a different method of achieving the above by manually placing the STM32F411 to sleep inside an ISR and omitting `HAL_PWR_EnableSleepOnExit()` inside the main function so it does not automatically sleep after the interrupt execution.

```
int main(){
   ...
   /* Sleep once until next interrupt occurs */
   HAL_SuspendTick();
   HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);
   HAL_ResumeTick();
   while(1){
      ...
   }
}
```

With the ISR for the STM32F411 being:

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin){

   if(GPIO_Pin == PushButton_Pin){
      /* Send data over SPI, where data is in pTxBuff and the length of data is cTxLen */
      HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)pTxBuff, cTxLen);

      /* Enter Sleep Mode after interrupt execution */
      HAL_SuspendTick();
      HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);
      HAL_ResumeTick();
   }

}
```

The method above does not work (only works with the first press of the push button on the STM32F411). Any reason why that is the case? I am planning to do something like this on a larger project, where the microcontroller sleeps until an interrupt occurs, then the microcontroller processes data in a while loop, and then go back to sleep until the next interrupt occurs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's a very exotic way of doing it. So the CPU stays in EXTI interrupt context while commanded to sleep, but will exit the interrupt context when it wakes up. But as the SPI data transfer you start also uses interrupts, you must make sure the SPI interrupt has higher priority than the EXTI interrupt, because otherwise the SPI interrupt can't interrupt the currently pending EXTI interrupt because it sleeps and no lower priority interrupts are accepted. I may not be 100% right here, but just so you know the pitfalls of that. I don't see the point why the CPU can't just sleep in the main loop?

Comment: I tried your method and it could also sleep upon entering the while loop. I was just curious as to why it was not working inside the interrupt.